# Find all numbers in a set of maxima that sum to a given number

Tags: algorithm, set, combinations

I am struggling to think of an algorithm which matches my needs.  I have a list of integers in a set, each integer represents a maximum value, the list can contain >= 1 entries.  I would like to find all the combinations of integers within these maxima that sum to a given value.

For example for a list of 4 maxima = [2, 3, 0, 5] and given value = 5, solutions are:

```
[2, 3, 0, 0]
[2, 2, 0, 1]
[2, 1, 0, 2]
[2, 0, 0, 3]
[1, 3, 0, 1]
[1, 2, 0, 2]
[1, 1, 0, 3]
[1, 0, 0, 4]
[0, 3, 0, 2]
[0, 2, 0, 3]
[0, 1, 0, 4]
[0, 0, 0, 5]
```

I have found some great algorithms related to this but they only address the combinations of the integers in the list which sum to the given value (i.e. in above example, would generate [2, 3] and [5] but not all the other combinations that I am interested in.

I have built a solution (in Swift) that solves this with blunt force (see below), but I am looking for something far more efficient.

```
import UIKit

let avail = [2, 3, 0, 5]
let sol = [0, 0, 0, 0]
var solList = [[Int]]()
let target = 5
let inc = 1
var calls = 0

generate(soln: sol, idx: 0)

print("calls : \(calls) solutions \(solList.count)")
for entry in solList {
    print(entry)
}

func generate(soln: [Int], idx: Int) -> Void {
    calls += 1
    
    let solnTotal = soln.reduce(0, +)
    
    if solnTotal > target {return}
    
    if solnTotal == target {
        solList.append(soln)
        //print(soln)
        return
    }
    
    if idx == soln.count {return}
    
    var tmp = soln[idx]
    while tmp <= avail[idx] {
        var solNext = soln
        solNext[idx] = tmp
        let solnTotal = solNext.reduce(0, +)
        if solnTotal > target {break}
        generate(soln: solNext, idx: idx + 1)
        tmp += inc
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I suppose your answer/solutions is not complete? Also because you didn't share any code or tags, we don't even know which language you want it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permutations in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960908/permutations-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks, The list above is the complete set of solutions to the example.  I will eventually be coding in Swift, but happy to have the algorithm in C, Java etc or Pseudocode.  Thanks for the pointer but, like all the other algorithms I have seen, these only handle permutations of the actual numbers in the list.  I am looking for another level of sophistication (as represented in my example above).

Comment: I don't get your solution then. Why do you allow [2,3,0,0] and [0,3,0,2] but no other variations? For example it's possible to write the combination of 5 and 0 in 4 different ways, you only have 1.

Comment: in my example, for the set {2, 3, 0, 5} I want the solutions where sum(a, b, c, d)  = 5 AND a<=2, b <=3, c <=0 and d<=5., and a, b, c, d >=0.   I think my list of solutions in the example is exhaustive.   The general statement of the problem is: for the set {a, b, c .... n} and a number X, find all the sets of the same cardinality as the given set, where sum(v, w, x .... z) = X and  0 <=  v  <= a and 0 <= w <= b and 0 <= x <= c and ... and 0 <= z <= n

Comment: The practical use is that each number in the set represents an amount of paint in  separate containers (say a holds 2pt, b holds 3pt, c is empty, d holds 5pt).  Given an empty mix container which holds X, what are all the combinations of amounts from each container which can be added to the mix container to give X (an amount of paint can be zero, but it is not possible to pour an amount greater than the individual paint container holds).  e.g, 2pt from a, 3pt from b is a solution as is, 3pt from b and 2pt from d but 1pt from c and 4pt from d is not a solution as c starts off empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253780/discussion-between-jim-burke-and-wimanicesir).

Comment: If you want to enumerate all combinations, you can't really do much better than brute force. However, if you only want to count the number of combinations that meet your criteria, that's a different story. Do you want to enumerate all combinations or do you just want to count/predict the number of such combinations? Also, it'd be helpful if you could post the constraints to your problem (list size and ranges for the maxima).

Comment: Thanks, yes, I wanted to enumerate.  Each maxima could be up to 100 - 200, and the examples using brute force take minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a python equivalent of the soln you provided in the question.

```
paints = [2, 3, 0, 5]
mix_bucket_size = 5

ans = []


def get_combinations(active_bucket, paint_selection):
    if active_bucket == len(paints):
        if sum(paint_selection) == mix_bucket_size:
            ans.append(paint_selection)
        return

    total_paint_used_till_now = sum(paint_selection)
    space_left_in_mix_bucket = mix_bucket_size - total_paint_used_till_now

    for amount_of_paint_selected_from_active_bucket in range(min(space_left_in_mix_bucket, paints[active_bucket]) + 1):
        new_paint_selection = list(paint_selection)
        new_paint_selection[active_bucket] = amount_of_paint_selected_from_active_bucket
        get_combinations(active_bucket+1, new_paint_selection)


get_combinations(0, [0,0,0,0])


for a in ans:
    print(a)
```

The problem is that a lot of duplicate computations are being done.
You can read up about DP memoization and edit your existing code to add a memoization map.
I solved this problem following a Divide and Conquer approach to avoid redundant calculations.

```
def get_combinations(paints, mix_bucket_size):
    if len(paints) == 1:
        if paints[0] >= mix_bucket_size:
            return [[mix_bucket_size]]
        else:
            return []
    else:
        all_combinations = []

        paints_length = len(paints)
        lp = list(paints[:paints_length // 2])
        rp = list(paints[paints_length // 2:])

        for left_bucket_size in range(mix_bucket_size + 1):
            left_combinations = get_combinations(lp, left_bucket_size)
            right_combinations = get_combinations(rp, mix_bucket_size - left_bucket_size)

            for i in left_combinations:
                for j in right_combinations:
                    all_combinations.append(list(i) + list(j))

        return all_combinations

ans = get_combinations([2, 3, 0, 5], 5)
print(len(ans))
```

I also compared the performance of the two for different input sizes:-

```
[2, 3, 0, 5] 5
Total Solutions: 12
Original Approach   : 3.0040740966796875e-05 
D&C Approach        : 3.2901763916015625e-05 

[2, 3, 0, 5, 4] 8
Total Solutions: 49
Original Approach   : 0.00012493133544921875 
D&C Approach        : 0.00016188621520996094 

[2, 3, 0, 5, 2, 8, 3] 10
Total Solutions: 746
Original Approach   : 0.0016598701477050781 
D&C Approach        : 0.0006949901580810547 

[2, 3, 0, 5, 2, 8, 3, 3, 8] 12
Total Solutions: 13899
Original Approach   : 0.02570486068725586 
D&C Approach        : 0.00564885139465332 

[2, 3, 0, 5, 6, 0, 3, 7, 6, 4] 15
Total Solutions: 39220
Original Approach   : 0.10733675956726074 
D&C Approach        : 0.016217708587646484 

[2, 3, 0, 5, 6, 0, 3, 7, 6, 4, 7] 18
Total Solutions: 276347
Original Approach   : 0.7197868824005127 
D&C Approach        : 0.1888890266418457 

[2, 3, 0, 5, 8, 3, 5, 2, 9, 0, 7, 6, 4] 20
Total Solutions: 4507603
Original Approach   : 12.061448097229004 
D&C Approach        : 2.8866631984710693
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is brilliant and helps me solve the problem.  I knew I would need a recursive approach and was thinking along the lines of your solution - but just couldn't think it through fully.  I really appreciate you taking the time to do this.  A great help!

Comment: I'm glad the code was readable @JimBurke . While running the performance tests I noticed the runtime for both approaches increases exponentially so large inputs will  time out both